# Codegear RAD Studio help system is corrupted

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I've been using **Codegear RAD Studio** for a over a year now but since the **"May08 Help Update"** the help system no longer works.  If I open the help the contents pane is entirely blank.  If I hit F1 I get the following error:  **"Unable to interpret the specified HxC file."**

I've searched for the answer using search engines and the Codegear forums but so far nothing seems to fix the problem.  I'd rather not do a full reinstall if possible.  Has anyone else experienced this issue and know how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need to do a complete uninstall/reinstall.  Alas.

Be sure to check http://docs.codegear.com for the latest in Delphi help. On that site you can also download the Delphi 2007 help in various forms, including PDF and CHM.

Comment: Nice to see someone from CodeGear on here. :)

Comment: What is the best way to reinstall to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You probably got a corrupted file from the download. I would try download again and reinstall the help.